# Makefile : Multiple targets in dedicated folders

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm struggling with the make language and haven't been yet able to reach my goal.
I have the following folder structure.

```
/sources/src => *.c
/sources/inc => *.h
/build => makefile
/build/target1/addsrc => *.c & *.h
/build/target2/addsrc => *.c & *.h
```

I want to compile both target using the command `make` or any target separately using one of the commands `make target1` or `make target2`. Each target uses the same sources located in the sources folder, adds additional sources located its own addsrc folder and applies different compilation flags. The makefile should create the following directories and files:

```
/build/target1/objects => *.o
/build/target1 => mylib.so
/build/target2/objects => *.o
/build/target2 => mylib.so
```

I tried with the following makefile:

```
targets=target1 target2

TARGET=$(dir $@)

DIR_OBJ     = $(TARGET)objects
DIR_BIN     = $(TARGET)
BIN         = mylib.so

DIR_SRC     = ../sources/src
DIR_ADDSRC_LOC = ./$(TARGET)addsrc
INCLUDES  = -I./$(TARGET)addsrc -I../sources/inc

SRC := $(notdir $(wildcard $(DIR_SRC)/*.c))
ifneq ($(DIR_ADDSRC_LOC),)
  SRCLOC := $(notdir $(wildcard $(DIR_ADDSRC_LOC)/*.c))
endif
SRCS = $(SRC) $(SRCLOC)

OBJ = $(SRCS:%.c=$(DIR_OBJ)/%.o)

CFLAGS  = -fPIC
LFLAGS = -shared -lm -Wl,--start-group -Wl,--no-undefined

all  : $(targets)

$(targets): % : %/init %/$(BIN) 

$(targets:%=%/init):
    @if [ ! -d $(DIR_OBJ) ]; then \mkdir -p $(DIR_OBJ); fi;
    @if [ ! -d $(DIR_BIN) ]; then \mkdir -p $(DIR_BIN); fi;

$(targets:%=%/$(BIN)): $(OBJ)
    gcc $(OBJ) $(LFLAGS) -o $@

$(DIR_OBJ)/%.o: %.c
    gcc $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

This works for the directory initialisation for each target. However, the rest is absolutely not working. I spent hours to have it working but without any success. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

Note: I haven't worked yet on the target dependency regarding the compilation flags.

Comment: You are indirectly using the `$@` automatic variable in the list of prerequisites. This cannot work because lists of prerequisites are expanded before `$@` gets a value. [Secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) could probably help but you would need to modify your rules to account for the double-expansion (`$$`...).

Comment: There are maybe other, potentially simpler, solutions than secondary expansion, but some information is missing in your question: what is this `addsrc / DIR_ADDSRC_LOC / init` stuff? Are these directories and source files already there? Shall they be copied from the main source? You apparently don't use this at all. Please clarify (in your question, not in comments)

Comment: And what about the header files? Do you have a regular scheme for the dependencies of object files with respect to header files? Do you want to automatically compute these dependencies? Do you want to ignore them completely?

Comment: Yes, the addsrc folder exists already for each target. In the folder structure tree, only the folders marked with a * at the begining don't exist. But my makefile was not yet complete to take into accound this addsrc folder. I wall try to update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have the gnu-make tag let's use GNU make:

```
targets  := target1 target2
BIN      := mylib.so
DIR_SRC  := ../sources/src
DIR_INC  := ../sources/inc
SRC      := $(wildcard $(DIR_SRC)/*.c)
OBJ      := $(patsubst $(DIR_SRC)/%.c,%.o,$(SRC))
CFLAGS   := -fPIC -I$(DIR_INC)
LDFLAGS  := -shared -Wl,--start-group -Wl,--no-undefined
LDLIBS   := -lm

.PHONY: all $(targets) clean
all: $(addsuffix /$(BIN),$(targets))

clean:
    rm -rf $(addsuffix /objects,$(targets)) $(addsuffix /$(BIN),$(targets))

$(targets): %: %/$(BIN)

%.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(addsuffix /objects,$(targets)):
    \mkdir -p $@

# $1: target
define target_rule
$1-LSRC := $$(wildcard $1/addsrc/*.c)
$1-LOBJ := $$(patsubst $1/addsrc/%.c,$1/objects/%.o,$$($1-LSRC))
$1-GOBJ := $$(addprefix $1/objects/,$$(OBJ))
$1-OBJ  := $$($1-LOBJ) $$($1-GOBJ)

$$($(1)-LOBJ): $1/objects/%.o: $1/addsrc/%.c
$$($(1)-GOBJ): $1/objects/%.o: $$(DIR_SRC)/%.c

$$($1-OBJ): CFLAGS += -I./$1/addsrc
$$($1-OBJ): | $1/objects

$1/$$(BIN): $$($1-OBJ)
    $$(CC) $$(CFLAGS) $$(LDFLAGS) -o $$@ $$^ $$(LDLIBS)
endef
$(foreach t,$(targets),$(eval $(call target_rule,$t)))
```

This makes use of GNU make specific features, especially the [foreach-eval-call](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function). It also uses [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) for the directories, and the the [standard make variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables) (`LDFLAGS`, `CC`, `LDLIBS`...) instead of the ones you were using.

Dependencies in the header files are not expressed because you do not explain what they should be. Adapt.

Demo:

```sh
$ tree
.
├── build
│   ├── makefile
│   ├── target1
│   │   └── addsrc
│   │       └── c.c
│   └── target2
└── sources
    ├── inc
    │   ├── a.h
    │   └── b.h
    └── src
        ├── a.c
        └── b.c

7 directories, 6 files
$ cd build
$ make
\mkdir -p target1/objects
\mkdir -p target2/objects
cc -fPIC -I../sources/inc -I./target1/addsrc -c target1/addsrc/c.c -o target1/objects/c.o
cc -fPIC -I../sources/inc -I./target1/addsrc -c ../sources/src/a.c -o target1/objects/a.o
cc -fPIC -I../sources/inc -I./target1/addsrc -c ../sources/src/b.c -o target1/objects/b.o
cc -fPIC -I../sources/inc -I./target2/addsrc -c ../sources/src/a.c -o target2/objects/a.o
cc -fPIC -I../sources/inc -I./target2/addsrc -c ../sources/src/b.c -o target2/objects/b.o
cc -fPIC -I../sources/inc -shared -o target1/mylib.so target1/objects/c.o target1/objects/a.o target1/objects/b.o -lm
cc -fPIC -I../sources/inc -shared -o target2/mylib.so target2/objects/a.o target2/objects/b.o -lm
$ make clean
rm -rf target1/objects target2/objects target1/mylib.so target2/mylib.so
$ make target1
\mkdir -p target1/objects
cc -fPIC -I../sources/inc -I./target1/addsrc -c target1/addsrc/c.c -o target1/objects/c.o
cc -fPIC -I../sources/inc -I./target1/addsrc -c ../sources/src/a.c -o target1/objects/a.o
cc -fPIC -I../sources/inc -I./target1/addsrc -c ../sources/src/b.c -o target1/objects/b.o
cc -fPIC -I../sources/inc -shared -o target1/mylib.so target1/objects/c.o target1/objects/a.o target1/objects/b.o -lm
$ make target2
\mkdir -p target2/objects
cc -fPIC -I../sources/inc -I./target2/addsrc -c ../sources/src/a.c -o target2/objects/a.o
cc -fPIC -I../sources/inc -I./target2/addsrc -c ../sources/src/b.c -o target2/objects/b.o
cc -fPIC -I../sources/inc -shared -o target2/mylib.so target2/objects/a.o target2/objects/b.o -lm
```

Comment: Looks very clean ! However, I face an error when trying that : `makefile:15: *** missing separator.  Stop.`. the line 15 seems to be `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@`. Note: I have `GNU Make 3.82`

Comment: Markdown rendering is not very happy with tabs, reason why you will frequently find spaces instead of tabs in Q&A on SO. Do not just copy-paste, replace the leading spaces in the recipes by tabs.

Comment: Yes, I confirm the missing tabs were the problem. Wonderful ! I'm now able to generate both targets using the command `make`. However, the single target generation (for example `make target1` is not working. I always get `make: 'target1' is up to date.`.

Comment: See my last update, I initially missed that you wanted partial builds. It should now work too.

Comment: I've partially solved the problem by replacing `all: $(addsuffix /$(BIN),$(targets))` by 
`all: $(targets)` and `$(targets): % : %/$(BIN)`
However, I've a problem in the end : it tries to compile a target1.o without corresponding target1.c. And this occurs after the lib creation. So I think the rest is correct, just this last command is erroneous.

Comment: Ah ok, I missed your last comment. Perfect, it works now. In my modification I didn't add the $(targets) targets to the .PHONY probably the cause of that last problem I had. One last detail : if I want to have a target dependant additional cflags (let's say TFLAGS). what is the best way to define them ? A variable `targetx-TFLAG` for each target ?

Comment: Yes, and then change the line `$$($1-OBJ): CFLAGS += -I./$1/addsrc` for `$$($1-OBJ): CFLAGS += -I./$1/addsrc $$($1-TFLAG)`.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I wanted. You saved me a lot of time. Thanks a lot !